# findbugs-maven-plugin:2.5.2:findbugs failed - java.io.EOFException: No input provided for project

Tags: maven-3, findbugs

My application is a multi module project. After upgrade to maven 3.0.5, find bugs plugin is failing on different modules for different builds. Below is the exception we get in the build log:

```
org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin:2.5.2:findbugs failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException: No input provided for project -> [Help 1]
[07:41:00]:  [Step 1/2] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin:2.5.2:findbugs (default-cli) on project straw-strait: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin:2.5.2:findbugs failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException: No input provided for project
```

mvn -X and -e gave below logs:

```
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime] [DEBUG] Goal:          org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin:2.5.2:findbugs (default-cli)
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime] [DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime] [DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime] <configuration>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime]   <classFilesDirectory default-value="${project.build.outputDirectory}"/>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime]   <compileSourceRoots>${project.compileSourceRoots}</compileSourceRoots>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime]   <debug default-value="false">${findbugs.debug}</debug>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime]   <effort default-value="Default">Max</effort>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime]   <failOnError default-value="true">${findbugs.failOnError}</failOnError>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime]   <findbugsXmlOutput default-value="true"/>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime]   <findbugsXmlOutputDirectory default-value="${project.build.directory}"/>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime]   <fork default-value="true">false</fork>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime]   <includeTests default-value="false">${findbugs.includeTests}</includeTests>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime]   <localRepository>${localRepository}</localRepository>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime]   <maxHeap default-value="512"/>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime]   <maxRank>20</maxRank>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime]   <nested default-value="false">${findbugs.nested}</nested>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime]   <outputDirectory default-value="${project.reporting.outputDirectory}"/>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime]   <outputEncoding default-value="${project.reporting.outputEncoding}">${outputEncoding}</outputEncoding>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime]   <pluginArtifacts>${plugin.artifacts}</pluginArtifacts>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime]   <project>${project}</project>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime]   <relaxed default-value="false">${findbugs.relaxed}</relaxed>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime]   <remoteArtifactRepositories>${project.remoteArtifactRepositories}</remoteArtifactRepositories>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime]   <remoteRepositories>${project.remoteArtifactRepositories}</remoteRepositories>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime]   <skip default-value="false">${findbugs.skip}</skip>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime]   <sourceEncoding default-value="${project.build.sourceEncoding}">${encoding}</sourceEncoding>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime]   <testClassFilesDirectory default-value="${project.build.testOutputDirectory}"/>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime]   <testSourceRoots>${project.testCompileSourceRoots}</testSourceRoots>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime]   <threshold default-value="Default">Default</threshold>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime]   <timeout default-value="600000"/>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime]   <trace default-value="false">${findbugs.trace}</trace>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime]   <xmlEncoding default-value="UTF-8"/>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime]   <xmlOutput default-value="false">true</xmlOutput>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime]   <xmlOutputDirectory default-value="${project.build.directory}"/>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime]   <xrefLocation default-value="${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/xref"/>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime]   <xrefTestLocation default-value="${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/xref-test"/>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime] </configuration>
[07:40:54]:      [com.dir.hay.straw:straw-prime] [DEBUG] =======================================================================
```

All my submodules are inheriting the plugin from the parent pom. I execute below maven command

```
mvn -T 1.5C clean install findbugs:findbugs
```

I see there is a [non reproduceable bug](https://jira.codehaus.org/i#browse/MFINDBUGS-170)

Comment: Do you have the same issue with findbugs-maven-plugin:2.5.4 instead?

Comment: Yes, same issue with 2.5.4 also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow findbugs does not like parallel build execution. When I removed the `-T` option, my build succeeded.

While building straw-prime project, it expects straw-strait project's reports I think, but because both are being built parallelly, it is not available at that moment. Hence build fails arbitrarily on different projects at different time